# change content-disposition on piped response

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following controller that get a file from the a service and pipes the answer to the browser.

```
function (req,res){
  request.get(serviceUrl).pipe(res);
}
```

**I'd like to change the content-disposition (from attachment to inline) so the browser opens the file instead of directly download it.**

I already tried this, but it is not working:

```
function (req,res){
  res.set('content-disposition','inline');
  request.get(serviceUrl).pipe(res);
}
```

The versions I'm using are:

- NodeJS: 0.12.x
- Express: 4.x

Comment: Can browsers open that file normally? If browser can't open the file it'll force the file to download.

Comment: yes it can. I saw in chrome's dev tools that the response is coming with content-disposition as it comes from the service ('attachment;filename=file.pdf').

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use an intermediate passtrhough stream between request and response, then headers from request won't be passed to response:

```
var through2 = require('through2'); // or whatever you like better

function (req, res) {
  var passThrough = through2(); // this stream is necessary to put correct response headers
  res.set('content-disposition','inline');
  request.get(serviceUrl).pipe(passThrough).pipe(res);
}
```

But be carefull, as this will ignore all headers, and you will probably need to specify 'Content-Type', etc.

Comment: I figured out why this works. The request module checks if the destination it is piping to has implements setHeaders, if it does it passes the headers along. If it doesn't, which a PassThrough stream won't, then it skips that step. [Here's the relevant part of the package's source](https://github.com/request/request/blob/3c0cddc7c8eb60b470e9519da85896ed7ee0081e/request.js#L1172-L1184)